# Mutually orthogonal subspaces of $L^{2}(X,\mu)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. If $E\in\mathcal{M}$, we identify $L^{2}(E,\mu)$ with the subspace of $L^{2}(X,\mu)$ consisting of functions that vanish outside $E$. If $\{E_{n}\}$ is a disjoint sequence in $\mathcal{M}$ with $X=\bigcup_{n}E_{n}$, then $\{L^{2}(E_{n},\mu)\}$ is a sequence of mutually orthogonal subspaces of $L^{2}(X,\mu)$. Show that every $f\in L^{2}(X,\mu)$ can be written uniquely as $f=\sum_{n}f_{n}$ (the series converging in norm) where $f_{n}\in L^{2}(E_{n},\mu)$. Moreover, show that if $L^{2}(E_{n},\mu)$ is separable for every $n$, then so is $L^{2}(X,\mu)$.

My attempt was to see that each $L^{2}(E_{n},\mu)$ is closed so $f$ has a unique expression as $f=f_{1}+g_{1}$ where $f_{1}\in L^{2}(E_{1},\mu)$ and $g_{1}\in L^{2}(E_{1},\mu)^{\perp}$. Inductively, I got $f=f_{1}+\cdots+f_{n}+g_{n}$ where $f_{i}\in L^{2}(E_{i},\mu)$ and $g_{n}\in L^{2}(E_{n},\mu)^{\perp}$. I am stuck at showing that the series converges in norm.

For the second part, I took a countable dense subset $A_{n}\subset L^{2}(E_{n},\mu)$ for each $n$, took $h_{n}\in A_{n}$ with $||f_{n}-h_{n}||<\varepsilon 2^{-n}$. Then $\sum_{n}h_{n}$ converges in norm and $||f-h||<\varepsilon$. But I'm not sure that the set of all $h$'s formed this way is a countable set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Take $f_n:=f\cdot \chi_{E_n}$, where $\chi_S$ is the characteristic function of the set $S$. For uniqueness, show that if $\sum_n g_n=0$, where $g_n\in L^2\left(E_n\right)$, then each $g_n=0$. To see that, multiply by $\chi_{E_j}$.
2. Fix $D_n$ a countable dense subset of $L^2(E_n,\mu)$, and $$V_n:=\left\{\sum_{j=1}^na_j,a_j\in D_j\right\}.$$
   Then $\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}V_n$ is countable. For a fixed $f$ and $\varepsilon>0$, take $N$ such that $\left\lVert f-\sum_{j=1}^{N}f_{j}\right\rVert<\varepsilon$ (which is possible since the sequence $\left(\sum_{j=1}^{N}f_{j}\right)_{ N\geqslant 1}$ converges to $f$ in the $\mathbb L^2$-norm), then approximate $\sum_{j=1}^Nf_j$ up to $\varepsilon$ by an element of $V_N$.

Comment: For (1), convergence follows from the dominated convergence theorem right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I forgot to write "uniquely" in the original post. How do I check uniqueness of the expression $f=\sum_{n}f_{n}$?

Comment: @learner See edit.

Comment: You mean $\sum_{j=1}^{N}f_{j}$ in your last line.

Comment: Why can we choose such an $N$? Is this from a result about series about which I probably do not know?

Comment: @Raptor There was a typo that I have corrected. Thanks.